# rails execute the view without execute the controller's action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, routes

I have a controller and an action in there, but  rails just show the view without execute the action.
I'm creating something like a contact_us, so I have in my routes

```
  get '/contact-us'     => 'desktop#contact_us'
  post '/contact_send'  => 'desktop#contact'
```

So, in contact-us, it show me the form, when I send the form rails show the contact_send view, but without execute the controller's action, nothing in there runs.

in my controller

```
  def contact_us

  end

  def contact_send
    contact_us = Contact.new user_params
    contact_us.save

    redirect_to '/contact-us', notice: 'Contact message was send successfully.'

  end
```

And in the form view it is just a form that is sending to /contact, and in taht view I just have text like "this is mi test view " to know it the view is showing", and the text is showing, but the controller action doesn't runs, even when i write and error on purpose

Comment: Can we see what the controller method(s) look like? Maybe the HTML form tag would help (so we can see the form action). You're not providing enough data to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `contact_send` is pointing to `desktop#contact` action. But your controller doesn't show a `contact` action. So your `contact_send` action isn't called.

Change

`post '/contact_send'  => 'desktop#contact'`

to

`post '/contact_send'  => 'desktop#contact_send'`

and check if this works.